In Sphinx How Do I Style a CSV-Table?
I have a simple csv-table directive in Sphinx that I would like to style:
Sphinx CSV-Table Styling
------------------------

.. csv-table:: Simple Example
   :header: a, b, c, d
   :widths: 5, 5, 5, 5

   1, 2, 3, 4
   5, 6, 7, 8
   9, 10, 11, 12
   13, 14, 15, 16

I would like to style the following:

Change the header background color.
Change the background of every other row.
Change the background of a single column.
Change the color of text for a single item.


The following is my solution:
.. raw:: html

   <style> 
    table.table1 th {background-color: lightgray}
    table.table1 tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: yellow}
    table.table1 td:nth-child(3) {background-color: orange}
    table.table1 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) {background-color: lightblue}
    .red {color: red}
   </style>


Sphinx CSV-Table Styling
------------------------

.. csv-table:: Simple Example
   :header: a, b, c, d
   :widths: 5, 5, 5, 5
   :class: table1

   1, 2, 3, 4
   5, 6, 7, 8
   :red:`9`, 10, 11, 12
   13, 14, 15, 16

Some things to note:

To deal with the table, header, rows, columns, and individual cell backgrounds, the key is setting the :class: in the csv-table directive and creating the appropriate CSS selectors.
To deal with the text in the table, the key is realizing that you can apply Sphinx roles (:red:) to individual bits of text and set the styling in a CSS class with a corresponding name (.red).

